# Boost Inteprocess shared memory - reading impossible just in one app

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I have three applications.

1. `Feeder` - creates a `boost::interprocess` shared memory object and fills it. `Feeder` is Qt based.
2. `Gui` - has lots of buttons and textboxes from which a structured config is created. `Gui` is Qt based.
3. `User` - reads the config created by `Gui` and connects to the shared memory filled by `Feeder`, then performs calculations. `User` is a console C++, no Qt.

The problem is that once `Feeder` fills the shared memory, `Gui` CAN access it, while `User` CAN NOT despite both `Gui` and `User` use the same code for reading the shared memory. Two years ago, with Qt 4.X this worked nicely, today I am on Qt 5.1.1. - I dont know whether there is a connection with Qt version.

Just for the sake of illustration, the code snippets are

**`Feeder`**

```
this->mem = new shared_memory_object(create_only, "tickChartSize",  read_write);
this->mem ->truncate(sizeof(unsigned int));
mapped_region region( *this->mem, read_write);
*((unsigned int))region.get_address()) = this->size();
```

**`Gui` + `User`**

```
shared_memory_object *mem = new shared_memory_object(open_only, "tickChartSize", read_only);
this->u = (void*)new mapped_region( *mem, read_only );  // works in Gui, throws in User
```

I went into the boost code and discovered the line that differs accross `Gui` and `User`, right before the throw in `User` - line 459 in mapped_region.hpp

```
 //Obtain mapping size if user provides 0 size
      if(size == 0){
         offset_t mapping_size;
THIS --> if(!winapi::get_file_mapping_size(native_mapping_handle, mapping_size)){
            error_info err = winapi::get_last_error();
            throw interprocess_exception(err);
         }
         //This can throw
         priv_size_from_mapping_size(mapping_size, offset, page_offset, size);
      }
```

Once the `winapi::get_file_mapping_size` call is finished, `mapping_size` in `Gui` is 8 while in `User` it is **-3689348814741910324**. The only information about the error is in `err` structure, however `err.m_ec = system_error(1)`, i.e. this message does not provide much help.

Build info:

- Qt 5.1.1
- boost 1.54.0
- Windows 7 x64
- Visual Studio 2012
- All apps are compiled as x64

Any help on this subject is much appreciated.

Daniel

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

Despite my original VS project worked without any apparent errors, creating the project anew made this buggy behavior disappear. Thanks to all viewers.

Answer (score 1):

The win32 implementation goes on to use NtQuerySection to get the size of the mapping:

```
inline bool get_file_mapping_size(void *file_mapping_hnd, __int64 &size)
{
   NtQuerySection_t pNtQuerySection =
      (NtQuerySection_t)dll_func::get(dll_func::NtQuerySection);
   //Obtain file name
   interprocess_section_basic_information info;
   unsigned long ntstatus =
      pNtQuerySection(file_mapping_hnd, section_basic_information, &info, sizeof(info), 0);
   size = info.section_size;
   return !ntstatus;
}
```

Error Code 1 on windows indicates `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`. This either means that this **[undocumented function from ntdll.dll](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Section/NtQuerySection.html)** is not accessible or it is not valid for use with the particular handle `file_mapping_hnd` passed.

Perhaps, armed with this information, you can find a cause or ask about it on the Boost mailing list

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I managed to get into these internals too, however pNtQuerySelection is already in some win32 dll and cant be entered in debug mode. I tried checking whether the absence/presence of Qt had something to do with the error and there seemed to be no connection. In the end, I discovered that my Visual Studio project must have gone bad, as when I created the same project anew, the code started to work. Still, thanks a lot.